# How to delete a row from datagrid by selecting a node from treenode?

Tags: c#, for-loop, datagridview, treeview

Iam entering data in datagridview in c# when i draw a rectangle on picturebox, i have an array where i store the rectangle data , whenever i enter a new row, i also create a new childnode in treeview. Now i want to delete a row in datagridview by selecting the corresponding treenode. But my code is not working properly. I mostly get out of range exception errors.

Please help me fix this?

This is my code to delete the row:

```
         int pos = (int) treeView1.SelectedNode.Tag;
         
            if (treeView1.SelectedNode.Name.Contains("Code"))
            {
                if (pos == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Cannot delete 1st node");
                }

                else
                {
                    treeView1.SelectedNode.Remove();

                    for (int i = pos; i < rectincr; i++)
                    {
                        PB1CodeRect[i] = PB1CodeRect[i + 1]; //delete rectangle with row and node
                        dataGridView2.Rows[i].Tag = pos;
                        dataGridView2.Rows[poss].Selected = true;

                        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dataGridView2.SelectedRows)
                        {
                            dataGridView2.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index); //delete dgvrow
                        }
                    }
                  
                   
                }
```

And this is the part of code where dgv and node is inserted.

```
       {
       PB1CodeRect[pb1Coderectincr] = new Rectangle(Convert.ToInt32(cibcam1.SelectionRegion.X), Convert.ToInt32(cibcam1.SelectionRegion.Y), Convert.ToInt32(cibcam1.SelectionRegion.Width), Convert.ToInt32(cibcam1.SelectionRegion.Height));
            pb1Coderectincr++;
            this.dataGridView2.Rows.Add(pb1Coderectincr, tabControl2.SelectedTab.Text, "2dCode - " + cibcam1.SelectionRegion.X + "," + cibcam1.SelectionRegion.Y + "," + cibcam1.SelectionRegion.Width + "," + cibcam1.SelectionRegion.Height,0);

            codenodcam1.Name = "Code ROI-" + pb1Coderectincr;
            codenodcam1.Text = "Code ROI-" + pb1Coderectincr;
            codenodcam1.Tag = pb1Coderectincr + 1;
           //var dict = (Dictionary<int, int>)codenodcam1.Nodes[0].Tag;
           // dict[pb1Coderectincr] = pb1Coderectincr;
            mainNode.Nodes.Add(codenodcam1);
            mainNode.ExpandAll();
           }
```

Comment: There are numerous questionable things in your current code, but, it is not clear how the `TreeView` and the grid rows are related. Where is `rectincr` defined and what is its value? Where is `PB1CodeRect` defined and what does it contain? And if the code you show is to delete a “single” row from the grid, then why is the code deleting ALL the “selected” rows? Sorry if I am missing something.

Comment: Also you may not be aware that… specifically looking at the `foreach` loop through the grids selected rows. If you remove a row from the grid as your code does with… `dataGridView2.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);` … then after that row is removed… would not the row “indexes” below that row change? I would think this would possibly mess up some of the row indexes in the `TreeView` unless you are changing them somewhere else.

Comment: @JohnG - Yes, exactly, it does messes up the indexes of other rows and node. I have updated my question with the part of code where the datagrid and node is inserted. Please help me.

Comment: @JohnG - PB1CodeRect[] is an array of rectangle, PB1CodeRectincr[] is increment array like an index, when a row and node is deleted i also want to delete the rectangle from the array.

Comment: Well… I still do not understand what purpose the `TreeView` plays in this. In addition to… _”PB1CodeRectincr[] is increment array like an index”_ … ? … sorry I may be missing something but I have no idea what an “increment” array is. I mean no disrespect, however, what ever you are trying to do… it appears you are making it unnecessarily complicated. I am just saying it appears you are juggling a grid, an array of rectangles, a second “increment” array, along with a TreeView? What on earth are you trying to doing here?

Comment: You state that you want to …. _” … delete a row in datagridview by selecting the corresponding treenode.”_ … ? … This is very odd and needs further explanation… “why” would you need to delete a tree node if a row in the grid is deleted? Also the corollary you state that… _”I am entering data in datagridview in c# when i draw a rectangle on picturebox, i have an array where i store the rectangle data , whenever i enter a new row, i also create a new childnode in treeview.”_ … ? … “Why” are you creating a new tree node when a new row is added to the grid?

Comment: You neglect to note that WE know nothing about what your code is supposed to do other than what YOU provide. Please explain how the Grid, the array of rectangles, the “increment” array, and the Tree View are supposed to work together. I would think that the grid should reflect what is in the rectangle array/list… i.e. … the GRIDS `DataSource` IS the array or list of rectangles. If you delete a rectangle from the rectangle list, then that row is “automatically” removed from the grid. Again this is speculation as it is not clear what you are trying to do in a big picture.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

In reply to JohnG's questions - im building an image processing application where I draw an ROI, the roi rectangle coordinates are saved in the PBRect[] array because there would be multiple rectangles. Each rectangle's coordinates, index, inspection result are stored in a row of DGV. The treeview is to allow the user easy access to manipulate ROI size, delete roi etc. The DGV is hidden from user view.

I made the mistake of adding pb1Coderectincr++ before i updated values, so the increment has to be the last one.

I also updated the DGV index value once a node, rect and row has been deleted so the index is not messed up. Here is the working code to delete node, row and rectangle:

```
       int pos = (int)treeView1.SelectedNode.Index;
       if (pos == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Cannot delete 1st node");
                }
                else
                {
                    treeView1.SelectedNode.Remove(); //delete node
                    for (int i = pos; i < pb1Coderectincr; i++) //delete rectangle
                    {
                        PB1CodeRect[i] = PB1CodeRect[i + 1];
                    }
                    dataGridView2.Rows[pos].Selected = true;
                    foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dataGridView2.SelectedRows) //delete dgv row
                    {
                        dataGridView2.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);
                        if (!item.IsNewRow) // update index
                        {
                            item.Cells[0].Value = item.Index + 1;
                        }
                    }
                    treeView1.Focus();
                }
```